# PDO MySQL Query only returning one set of results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I built a search form for an app and it is currently only pulling back on result at a time where there should be multiples. I am sure this is something dumb and was wondering if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

// php search data in mysql database using PDO
// set data in input text

$TaskId = "";
$ClientId="";
$TaskName = "";
$TaskDescription = "";
$TaskStartAt = "";


if(isset($_POST['Find']))
{
    // connect to mysql
try {
    $pdoConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tt","root","root");
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
}

// id to search
//$TaskId = $_POST['TaskId'];
$ClientId = $_POST['ClientId'];
// date to search
//$DateCreated = $_POST['DateCreated'];

 // mysql search query
$pdoQuery = "SELECT * 
FROM tasks t 
left join users u using (UserId)
left join clients cl using (ClientId)
WHERE t.isdeleted = 0 and  ClientId = :ClientId";

$pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);

//set your id to the query id

$pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":ClientId"=>$ClientId));


if($pdoExec)
{
        // if id exist 
        // show data in inputs
    if($pdoResult->rowCount()>0)
    {
        echo '<table>';
        foreach   
        ($pdoResult as $rows)
        {
            //$TaskId = $row['TaskId'];
            $ClientId = $rows['ClientId'];
           // $TaskName = $row['TaskName'];
           // $TaskDescription = $row['TaskDescription'];
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
        // if the id not exist
        // show a message and clear inputs

   }else{
    echo 'ERROR Data Not Inserted';
  }
}


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Task Tracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/demo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/header-fixed.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie' rel='stylesheet'    type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//Display the Month Date and Time on login.
function display_c(){
 var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
var strcount
var x = new Date()
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
tt=display_c();
}
</script>

 </head>
<body>

<header class="header-fixed">
<div class="header-limiter">

    <h1><a href="#">Task Tracker</a></h1>




    <nav>
        <a href="dashboard.php" class =>Dashboard</a>
        <a href="addtask.php" class=>Task Management</a>
  <a href="configuration.php" class =>Configuration</a>
  <a href="logout.php" class =>Logout</a>
  <a href="search.php" class ="selected">Reports & Analytics</a>

    </nav>
    </nav>

   </div>
  </header>

    <title> Query a task</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

   </head>

    <form action="search.php" method="post">

       <!--  Enter a Task Id : <input type="text" name="TaskId" value=""> <br><br> -->
        Enter a Client Id : <input type="text" name="ClientId" value="<?php echo $ClientId;?>"><br><br>



        <input type="submit" name="Find" value="Find Data">

        <br> </br>


        <table border="0">
        <tr COLSPAN=2 BGCOLOR="lightblue">
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Client</td>
        <td>Task Name</td>
        <td>Task Description</td>
        <td>Hours</td>
        <td>Date Created</td>
        <td>Who Completed Task</td>
   </tr>
    <?php     
    {

   if($pdoResult->rowCount()>0) 

    {
  echo "<tr>".
       "<td>".$rows["TaskId"]."</td>".
       "<td>".$rows["ClientName"]."</td>".
       "<td>".$rows["TaskName"]."</td>".
       "<td>".$rows["TaskDescription"]."</td>".
       "<td>".$rows["Hours"]."</td>".
       "<td>".$rows["DateCreated"]."</td>".
       "<td>".$rows["UserName"]."</td>".
       "</tr>";
    }

   else{
        echo 'No data associated with this Id';
    }

 }
?>

</table>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there any fetching done for the result set?

Comment: @frz3993 yes just one no matter if there are multiple results for the entry of the client Id

Comment: I don't see any `fetch()` or `fetchAll()` in your code.

Comment: @frz3993 You don’t actually have to fetch the results for them to be stored in the `PDOStatement` object—fetching them just creates a variable of the type specified to hold the result set. The statement object itself also holds all the rows returned, and it is iterable, so `foreach`-ing through the statement object essentially gives you the same result, just with less control.

Answer (score 4):

At a quick glance, it seems to be simply that you’ve split your functionalities up too much.

At the top of the page, you establish your database connection and retrieve the result set. Then you echo a `table` element, `foreach` through the PDO Statement object and assign the contents of the current row to the variable `$rows`. Note: the content of the **current row**.

Further down on the page, you `echo` the individual fields, using `$rows['field']`—but you do this **outside** your `foreach` loop. Since `$rows` gets repopulated everytime the loop loops around, and since you don’t destroy the variable after the loop completes, you end up at the end with a variable that still contains the last row from your result set.

You need to put the place where you actually print the contents of each individual row *inside* the loop that iterates through your statement object to retrieve the fields. On the other hand, you only want to do this at all if any user input has been entered at all, so the whole thing still needs to be inside the positive branch of the very first condition that checks if `$_POST['Find']` is set, like in the version below.

I start out here by assigning a variable `$results` to be an empty string—that’s the value we’ll output if the user hasn’t sent the form at all. If `$_POST['Find']` is not empty, then we search the database, iterate through the result set, create an HTML string in this loop, and store the result in the `$results` variable. If no rows are returned or the `execute()` call fails entirely, we throw an exception to be handled by an exception handler (that you will have to define at a central level, for your entire project), passing along a generic error message to be displayed to the user.

Note that I’ve also stripped out a lot of extraneous stuff and comments to make the relevant bits clearer and renamed the `$rows` variable to `$row` to make it clear that since it’s populated inside a loop, it contains **one** row, not all of them.

```
<?php

// Set the global exception handler—should of course be done
// in a global boilerplate file, rather than for each file
set_exception_handler('your_exception_handler_here');
$results = "";

if(!empty($_POST['Find']))
{
    $pdoConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tt","root","root");
    $pdoConnect->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $ClientId = $_POST['ClientId'];

    $pdoQuery = "SELECT * 
    FROM tasks t 
    left join users u using (UserId)
    left join clients cl using (ClientId)
    WHERE t.isdeleted = 0 and  ClientId = :ClientId";

    $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);
    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":ClientId"=>$ClientId));

    if($pdoResult->rowCount()>0)
    {
        $results = '<table border="0">
            <tr COLSPAN=2 BGCOLOR="lightblue">
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Client</td>
                <td>Task Name</td>
                <td>Task Description</td>
                <td>Hours</td>
                <td>Date Created</td>
                <td>Who Completed Task</td>
            </tr>';

        foreach ($pdoResult as $row)
        {
            $ClientId = $row['ClientId'];
            $results .= "<tr>".
                "<td>".$row["TaskId"]."</td>".
                "<td>".$row["ClientName"]."</td>".
                "<td>".$row["TaskName"]."</td>".
                "<td>".$row["TaskDescription"]."</td>".
                "<td>".$row["Hours"]."</td>".
                "<td>".$row["DateCreated"]."</td>".
                "<td>".$row["UserName"]."</td>".
                "</tr>";
        }
            $results .= "</table>";
    } else {
        $return = '<span class="error_message">No data associated with this Id</span>');
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Task Tracker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <title>Query a task</title>
    <form action="search.php" method="post">
        Enter a Client Id : <input type="text" name="ClientId" value="<?php echo $ClientId;?>"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Find" value="Find Data">
    </form>

    <?php
        echo $results;
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A good answer in general, but you missed some logic from the OP. Your nested condition makes no sense, which made a comment "show data in inputs" quite misplaced

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't quite follow you there. The nested condition makes perfect sense as far as I can see: check if the query execution was successful, then check if any rows were returned. Am I missing something? “Show data in inputs” doesn't make much sense, I'll admit, but it didn't in the question either—the data is shown in table rows both places.

Comment: Your explanations doesn't follow with the error message this condition outputs. Either way, checking for $pdoExec variable is superfluous and have to be avoided.

Comment: Either way, your post is better than 99% of answers given under PDO tag, so you are more than welcome to keep answering, the tag needs participants like you.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Do you mean the “ERROR Data Not Inserted” message? I just took that from the question, assuming that it makes sense in the asker’s workflow. To me, a more logical message to output would be something like “An error occurred while trying to fetch data from the database”. I don’t agree that checking for `$pdoExec` is superfluous and should be avoided; if, for some reason, the query execution itself fails, you want to catch that. I just realised that this should still be done inside the positive branch of the condition that checks if any user input has been given, though. Fixing.

Comment: In case of error (given PDO was properly configured) your execution will never reach this condition. And never should be. Of course you want to handle errors. But doing it for the every line of code would be insane. Therefore you should have a centralized error handler and thus never write error reporting code in your application.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I agree that error handling should be centralised, but since I don’t have any knowledge of what else is going on in the project, I opted for just maintaining an error message. Making sure that every line in your code will degrade gracefully _if_ an error of some type occurs does not sound insane to me. Unfortunately, `PDOStatement::execute` doesn’t do anything useful for easy error handling, it just returns false, so you’ll pretty much have to check its return value one way or another to find out if it failed.

Comment: It does. It raises an exception, which is all that a developer would ever want.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You’re right, it does. I’m not sure where I have it from, but I’ve been going around thinking for as long as I can recall that `execute()` stupidly did not throw any exceptions on failure. Just tested it now, and sure enough, it throws a `PDOException` like you’d expect it to. Will add that into the answer.

Comment: Perfect. Just added the line that makes PDO actually to throw exceptions